# Poincaré-Miranda Theorem applications

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

Recently I become interested in the Poincaré-Miranda Theorem and I thought that it could be really useful. However, while looking now for more non-trivial applications of the Poincaré-Miranda Theorem almost everything I find is very theoretical.

I have found some interesting papers such as ["Periodic orbits of discrete and continuous dynamical systems via Poincaré-Miranda theorem"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.06208) and ["Periodic points of a Landen transformation"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.04195), which both provide applications of it.

I would appreciate if someone could provide some references on non-trivial applications of the Poincaré-Miranda, either applied in dynamical systems or in any other field.